# Json empty return

Tags: json, is-empty

```
$alfa = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats   /GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=$key&steamid=$steamid");
$beta =  json_decode($alfa);
```

Sometimes, $steamid (actualy the user with that steamid) don't have that Game (710) and array it's empty ... and i don't know how to make a verification if that array it's empty or not...

You can check this with $steamid = 76561198010791116 and key from here http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey

What's the function for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `empty()` function a try: http://php.net/manual/function.empty.php

```
if(empty($beta)) {
   // array $beta is empty
}
```

Comment: The problem is if he doesn't  game, website returns this Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamid=76561198010791116): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  ..... Then echo for empty... @Lantzsch

Comment: Then try this: `$response = @file_get_contents('...'); if($response === false) { // error ocurred }`

Comment: With @ for debug and if($alfa == null) works.. Thank you for idea !